# prove that $B(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{F}(L^1(\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

> For $p=1,2,$ let $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of Lebesgue measurable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ so that $\lVert f\rVert_p < \infty,$ where $\lVert f\rVert_1 := \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|dx$ and $\lVert f\rVert_2 := (\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2dx)^{1/2}$. Let for $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}), f\star g = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)g(x-y) dy.$ Let $B(\mathbb{R}) = \{f\star g :f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}.$ Prove $B(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{F}(L^1(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathcal{F}(f) = \hat{f}, \hat{f}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-itx} dx$ for all $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

> Prove that $B(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{F}(L^1(\mathbb{R}))$.

> Prove that $B(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

I know some properties of $f\star g$ such as the fact that $\lVert f\star g\rVert_p \leq \lVert f\rVert_p \lVert g\rVert_1$ for $p=1,2$. Also, the set of continuous compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and it's usually easier to work with these functions when integrating (E.g. Fubini's theorem applies). Also, I know that $f(x) = \lim\limits_{A\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-A}^A \hat{f}(t) e^{itx} dx$ for almost every $x$ when $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f}(x) = \lim\limits_{A\to\infty} \int_{-A}^A f(t) e^{-itx} dx$ for almost every $x$ when $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ .

Answer (score 1):

The  Fourier transform is an isometry onto $L^2(\mathbb R)$ (up to a constant factor), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem.

Moreover, the Fourier transform maps convolution to multiplication, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem. Thus the question is equivalent to showing that
$$\{h u \, :\,  h,u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}=L^1(\mathbb{R}) .$$
Given $h,u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$,the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that
$hu \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) .$ Conversely, given $\psi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) ,$
take $h=\text{sgn}(\psi)\cdot \sqrt{|\psi|}$ and $u=  \sqrt{|\psi|}$ so that
$h,u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you further justify why the question's equivalent to showing your claim (i.e. that $\{hu :h,u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\} = L^1(\mathbb{R})$? Alternatively, would it be possible to show the claim directly? I keep trying to show that $\hat{fg} = f\star g$ for $f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ but without success. Could you show this or something similar (in case it's false)?

Comment: I added the relevant references. They should allow you to construct a direct proof if you like. If you try and run into a difficulty, please let me know precisely where. Note that the Fourier transform of functions in $L^2$ is defined by extending the integral formula in the classical definition, which is directly defined only for functions in $L^1$.